# How to work around delimiters in CSV files using opencsv

Tags: java, opencsv

A CSV file contains two kinds of data (bad):

```
1. "ABC\"
2. "ABC\""
```

When I specify in opencsv to not consider any escape sequence, the first scenario works, but fails for the second since it ends with two double quotes.

When I specify another character as an escape sequence, again the first scenario works, but fails for the second since it ends with two double quotes.

The only goal for me is to parse this data, it can parse it as `ABC`, `ABC\` or `ABC\"`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about replacing two consecutive quotes with one before parsing.

Comment: I searched online but no luck ! Any chance you would know how to do that 
 using opencsv in Java?

Comment: `yourcsvString.replaceAll("\\\"\"", "\\\"")`

Comment: There are values like ""BB"" which parses as it is, hence replacing by the above method is not a solution.

Comment: Can you mention any other edge case ?

Comment: Just the one's I mentioned above

Comment: In that case `yourcsvString.replaceAll("\"\"", "\"")` should work, giving you ABC\ and BB.

If you want ABC and BB use `yourcsvString.replaceAll("\\\"\"", "\"").replaceAll("\"\"", "\"")`

Comment: Is there any other option other than replacing characters??

Comment: I am not sure what you want. You do have the option to open it in text editor and fix it manually.

Comment: I am not allowed to change anything in the csv file. Hence replacing is not an option. The csv file needs to parsed successfully without any errors. That's the goal !!

Comment: In that case it seems fairly impossible.

Answer (score 0):

openCSV with the RFC4180Parser (or any java csv parser library with RFC4180 compatibility) should parse the first one as ABC\ and the second one as ABC\".

That said if there is data that you know is bad and you don't want it in your final output then you should follow Brahma's suggestion as it is the application's responsibility to handle bad data as you may not like how the library handles (or mishandles) it.

:)

You are going to have to give a code example because I wrote the following test and it passes (My results were ABC\ and ABC\"):

```
@Unroll
def 'sof request - parsing #value yields #expected'(String value, String expected) {
    given:
    RFC4180ParserBuilder builder = new RFC4180ParserBuilder()
    RFC4180Parser parser = builder.build()
    String[] parsedValues = parser.parseLine(value)

    expect:
    parsedValues.length == 1
    parsedValues[0] == expected

    where:
    value            | expected
    "\"ABC\\\""      | "ABC\\"
    "\"ABC\\\"\""    | "ABC\\\""

}
```

Comment: The RFC4180Parser did not work for "ABC\"" cell value.

Comment: Please help @scott